# Seeing the content of a script sourced in a Markdown document (RStudio)

Tags: markdown, rstudio

I just want to print the content of an R script sourced in another location.

````
```{r Model}
source("~/Desktop/model_sim_simple_that_I_want_to_show.R")
```
````

But this is just sourcing the script and not showing it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just read the lines and then write them back out:

````
```{r Model, comment=NA}
cat(paste(readLines("~/Desktop/model_sim_simple_that_I_want_to_show.R), collapse="\n"))
```
````